# How to rank the dictionaries using its values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have:

```
a=[{"name":"XXX", "punch":20},{"name":"yyy", "punch":19},{"name":"zzz", "punch":5}]
```

**Result:**

```
 result = [{"name":"xxx","medal":"Bronze"},{"name":"yyy","medal":"Silver"},{"name":"zzz","medal":"Gold"}]
```

The result will be based on punch.

Comment: what is the codition?

Comment: case: 1  (gold, silver, bronze)
case:2   (gold, gold, bronze)
case:3   (gold, silver, silver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the list items on `punch`, then iterate the sorted list, and `['Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold']` in parallel using `zip`, finally get the resulting list:

```py
>>> [{'name':d['name'], 'medal':medal}
    for d, medal in zip(sorted(a, 
                                key=lambda x: x['punch'], reverse=True),
                        ['Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold'])]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[{'name': 'XXX', 'medal': 'Bronze'},
 {'name': 'yyy', 'medal': 'Silver'},
 {'name': 'zzz', 'medal': 'Gold'}]
```

Comment: Great solution! Actually, I think it would be even better not to use `reverse` and sort the medal array from `Gold` to `Bronze`. that way you can still award medal to the best/lowest scoring players even if the dictionary is longer.

Comment: Rank method is not applicable for this case.

Comment: That is `True`, But lists are ordered collection, and if  we do that, the dictionary will be sorted from higher to lower @Tranbi

Comment: Also true! In the end it depends on how OP plans to use his code...

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```
a = [{"name":"XXX", "punch":20},{"name":"yyy", "punch":19},{"name":"zzz", "punch":5}]     
result = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['punch'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can sort it first, then pair the punch number with the medals, and last delete the punch key.

```
a = [{"name":"XXX", "punch":20},{"name":"yyy", "punch":19},{"name":"zzz", "punch":5}]
result = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['punch'])

medel = ['brown', 'silver', 'gold']
for i, _ in enumerate(result):
    result[i]['medel'] = medel[i]
    del result[i]['punch']

print(result)
>>>[{'name': 'zzz', 'medel': 'brown'},
>>> {'name': 'yyy', 'medel': 'silver'},
>>> {'name': 'XXX', 'medel': 'gold'}]
```

I believe it must has other easy to deal with it, but I hope this could help you with your problem.